# Problem installing skype

Tags: google-play-store, asus-eee-pad-transformer

I am running android 4.1.1 on asus transformer tf300t.

When trying to install skype using the google play, i am getting: unknown error 24

All other applications I am trying to install are working without any problem. I have no idea what to do, and I really need to have skype on my device.

Any idea what to do about it?

thanks

Comment: If all else fails, download or take the ".apk" from a friend or simply use Google+ Hangouts.